# FreeRadius3 support rlm_jradius?

Tags: java, freeradius

we are using the FreeRadius 2.2.9 version and Jradius 1.1.4

but because FreeRadius 2.x end of life, so we plan to upgrade FreeRadius to 3.x
unfortunately, the FreeRadius 3.x not support rlm_jradius module, how can we handle this case
because we want to re-use the jradius code, does anyone know this?

thanks,
Bryan

some one can guide me how FreeRadius3 support java radius server

Answer (score 1):

For test usage. You can make some private changes from Jradius git hub project post
https://github.com/coova/jradius/pull/43/files#diff-22df313f4daa5f10565dceb10cfc4d436ade0f365e63724747db63f608d50f3c

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

FreeRADIUS v3 no longer support jradius. You will need to find another solution.

It was removed in 2013 because jradius changed their protocol, see the comments on the commit: https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/commit/1b35db797dd429944d2b9919dd689721cd021f39

Comment: Yes, you are right Matthew, seems Jradius side should do some changes to meet the V3 free-radius.